# How to handle mutliple output filename conventions with Snakemake

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I have a scenario where the output filenames of a program are not consistent and hence I am having difficulty defining snakemake rules.

I am retrieving data from SRA  and I do not know if the program will return 1 file or 2 files

Here are the 2 situations :

Situation 1

```
Retrieve SE data - this generates 1 output file named SRR5597649_1.fastq.gz

parallel-fastq-dump --sra-id SRR5597649 --threads 16 --outdir out/ --gzip --skip-technical --readids --dumpbase --split-files --clip
```

Situation 2

```
Retrieve PE data - this generates 2 output files SRR390728_1.fastq.gz  SRR390728_2.fastq.gz

parallel-fastq-dump --sra-id SRR390728 --threads 16 --outdir out/ --gzip --skip-technical --readids --dumpbase --split-files --clip
```

I would like to know from the Snakemake community how they would address the above situation and how would one define the individual rules and also the `rule:all`

***Note***: I am adding more information to this question after trying out @dariober solution

**Snakefile**

```
shell.executable("bash")
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

configfile: "config.json"

data_dir=os.getcwd()

units_table = pd.read_table("Samples.txt")
samples= list(units_table.Samples.unique())

rule all:
    input:
       expand("raw_fastq/{sample}.dump.done", sample=samples),
       expand("results/salmon/{sample}_salmon_quant",sample=samples),
       expand("results/logs/salmon/{sample}.salmon.log",sample=samples)

rule clean:
     shell: "rm -rf .snakemake/"

include: 'rules/download_sra.smk'
include: 'rules/salmon_quant.smk'
```

**download_sra.smk**

```
rule download_sra:
    """
    Download RNA-Seq data from SRA.
    """
    output: touch("raw_fastq/{sample}.dump.done"),
    params:
        outdir = "raw_fastq",
        threads = 16
    priority:85
    shell: "parallel-fastq-dump --sra-id {wildcards.sample} ... "
```

**salmon_quant.smk**

```
rule salmon_quant:
     input:
             touchfile = 'raw_fastq/{sample}.dump.done',
             index = config['salmon_rat_gentrome_Index']
     output:
             directory("results/salmon/{sample}_salmon_quant")
     log:
             'results/logs/salmon/{sample}.salmon.log'
     priority: 85
     threads: 20
     run:
        fq= sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join('raw_fastq',  wildcards.sample + '_[12].fastq.gz')))

        if len(fq) == 1:
            shell("salmon quant -i {input.index} -l A  -r %s  ..." % fq) # Process as SE
        elif len(fq) == 2:
            shell("salmon quant -i {input.index} -l A -1 %s -2 %s ...." % (fq[0], fq[1])) # Process as PE
        else:
            raise Exception('Wrong number of fastq files!')
```

**Problem I am facing**: When I try the solution suggested by  'dariober', there seems to be something wrong when the `%s` is being replaced when the shell command runs. Like for example, it is getting replaced as

`-r ['raw_fastq/SRR5597645_1.fastq.gz']`

whereas it should **have been replaced as**

`-r raw_fastq/SRR5597645_1.fastq.gz`

Probably, I am getting it wrong somewhere - as shown in the code above, the `%s`  is causing a tagging along a square bracket and a single quote.

Also, I would like to have this wrapped with a `temp` directive in the download_sra rules such that the fastq files and touchfiles can be deleted automatically after the job finishes.

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: To fix the square brackets problem use `fq[0]` instead of `fq` when `len(fq)==1` (my bad in my answer). Other things... It doesn't make sense to have the `.done` files in the `rule all` if you want to delete them with `temp`. I'm not sure `rule clean` is ever executed because it doesn't produce any output file. Anyway, it's probably not a good idea to forcefully delete the `.snakemake` dir. Let snakemake handle it. See also https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#onstart-onsuccess-and-onerror-handlers

Comment: Thanks @dariober - Sorry for my late response as I was busy with other things. Using fq[0] when len(fq)==1 works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution may be to touch a file when fastq-dump has completed and use that file as input to the other rules.

In the case you posted, the name of the actual fastq files can be reconstructed from the SRR id and you can tell whether you have 1 or 2 fastq files based on the suffix `_1.fastq.gz` or `_2.fastq.gz`.

Here's an example:

```
import glob
import os

sra_id= ['SRR1234', 'SRR4567']

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{sra_id}.dump.done', sra_id= sra_id),
        expand('{sra_id}.bam', sra_id= sra_id),

rule sra_dump:
    output:
        touch('{sra_id}.dump.done'),
    shell:
        r"""
        parallel-fastq-dump --sra-id {wildcards.sra_id} ... 
        """

rule align:
    input:
        '{sra_id}.dump.done',
    output:
        '{sra_id}.bam',
    run:
        fq= sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(wildcards.sra_id, wildcards.sra_id + '_[12].fastq.gz')))

        if len(fq) == 1:
            shell("bwa mem %s ..." % fq) # Process as SE
        elif len(fq) == 2:
            shell("bwa mem %s %s ..." % (fq[0], fq[1])) # Process as PE
        else:
            raise Exception('Wrong number of fastq files!')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this out. 

Can the rule be combined with a ```temp``` directive on both the fastq files outputted and the ```touch``` files - I ask this as I do not need files after pipeline

I am trying something like this 

rule download_sra:
     output: temp("raw_fastq/{sample}_[12].fastq.gz"), touch("raw_fastq/{sample}.dump.done")
    params:
        outdir = "raw_fastq",
       shell: "parallel-fastq-dump --sra-id {wildcards.sample} .... "

Comment: You cannot have `rule download_sra: output: temp("raw_fastq/{sample}_[12].fastq.gz")` since for SE files snakemake will fail bacause the `*_2.fastq.gz` was not produced (that's the reason for touching the `*.done` file). But yes, you can put the `temp` directive on the `.done` file. To delete the fastq files I would add a `os.remove(fq)` at the end of `align` rule